# Misleading javadoc comment on StringBuilder indexOf?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I'm trying to understand the following comment from the javadoc of the StringBuilder class's [indexOf(String str,
          int fromIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

It says:

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index. The integer returned is the smallest value k for which:
>
> ```
>     k >= Math.min(fromIndex, str.length()) &&
>                   this.toString().startsWith(str, k)
> ```
>
> If no such value of k exists, then -1 is returned.

Now, I can't see the reason for `str.length()` in `Math.min(fromIndex, str.length())` since it would allow for a String to be found on an index < fromIndex. Am I missing something, or this is simply a misleading/wrong commment?

**Edit**: [as pointed below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076927/misleading-javadoc-comment-on-stringbuilder-indexof/17077200?noredirect=1#comment24698831_17077200) this is the comment from the Java 7 javadoc; java 6 has the right comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mistake. It's supposed to be `this.length()` instead of `str.length()`.

That allows for `fromIndex` to be greater than `this.length()` in the case where `str` is empty.

Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Example");
System.out.println(sb.indexOf("", 1234)); //Outputs sb.length(), which is 7.
```

Note: [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) behaves the same way.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the [Java 7 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) defines `String#indexOf(String, int)` differently from the [Java 6 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), although it behaves the same way in both versions. The Java 6 doc has the correct definition.

Answer (score 0):

No the condition basically boils down to the first k such that k is at least `fromIndex` and less than or equal to `str.length()`, at which the string contains the desired substring.

If `str.length() < fromIndex`, then the `startsWith` condition will *always* be false, because `str.length()` is not a valid index to the generated string.

Comment: Ok. If you consider `str` to be the referenced StringBuilder it makes sense. But `str` is the parameter name and "the substring for which to search". I can understand now, and I guess that's what's wrong with the comment.